# Why Selenium tests take more than double time if I run multiple concurrent tests using ProcessPoolExecutor?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, parallel-processing, concurrent.futures

I have code that launches remote Selenium driver connections to a different server.
Each process/thread gets its own driver object and also its own MysqlDB cursor object.

```
class MyCustomCode(object):

    how_many_tests_to_run = 100

    def get_MySQLdb_connection(self):
        MySQLdb.connect(...)
        return cursor

    def start(self):
        with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
            all_jobs=[]
    
            for job_number in range(self.how_many_tests_to_run):
                job = executor.submit(
                    self.run_session, 
                    job_number
                )
                all_jobs.append(job)
                for future in futures.as_completed(all_jobs):
                    print(f"{future.result()} finished")

    def run_session(self, job_number):
        
        cursor = self.get_MySQLdb_connection()

        driver = webdriver.Remote(
                command_executor="my-ip:4444/wd/hub",
        )
        driver.implicitly_wait(0)

        #some DB interactions
        cursor.execute(.....)

        for page in driver.find_elements('.pages'): # click on 10 pages
            page.click()
            print(f'job_number={job_number} clicking on page {page.get_attribute("href")}')

        #some DB interactions
        cursor.execute(.....)

        return job_number
    
if __name__ == "__main__":

    obj = MyCustomCode()
    obj.start()
```

If I have `how_many_tests_to_run = 1` then that **one test takes like 5 minutes** and I can see the logs that its clicking on next pages with just 2-3 seconds apart.

```
00:00 job_number=1 clicking on page 1
00:02 job_number=1 clicking on page 2
00:05 job_number=1 clicking on page 3
00:07 job_number=1 clicking on page 4
00:08 job_number=1 clicking on page 5
.
.
.
```

Now lets talk about the issue I am having

If I set `how_many_tests_to_run = 100`. I can see all 100 tests are launched on my remote server.
But each one of them processes extremely slow.
And logs looks like this

```
00:00 job_number=1 clicking on page 1
00:12 job_number=1 clicking on page 2
00:20 job_number=1 clicking on page 3
00:29 job_number=1 clicking on page 4
00:45 job_number=1 clicking on page 5
.
.
.
```

Click on subsequent pages is more than 10 seconds apart. And **all sessions take like ~15 minutes to complete**.

I have tried both `ProcessPoolExecutor` and `ThreadPoolExecutor` and runtime is always ~15 minutes.

### Goal

If one session takes 5 minutes then **what I want is that whether I launch 50 tests or 100 tests then entire script should finished in 5 minutes**, if not under 7-8 minutes.
I don't care if I have to use some other library or module of Python.

### Server Details

```
lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

---

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          125Gi        26Gi       9.2Gi        50Mi        89Gi        97Gi
Swap:         4.0Gi        16Mi       4.0Gi
```

---

```
lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Address sizes:                   43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          64
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-63
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              32
```

Full output of lscpu command is [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/uMZxVPgY)

---

```
python -V
Python 3.10.7
```

Comment: Some wild guesses: It looks like you are running a lot of processes. Each process needs to pickle/unpickle objects including complex ones like MySQL objects which might be expensive and cause some weird behaviour. Besides, there are more processes than cores so this can introduce scheduling issues (certainly not causing a x4 overhead though). If you write in the DB, this can slow down other reads and cause contention effects (so be slower than the serial operation). Pages might be reused in some cases thanks to the COW mechanism but if you are on a NUMA system, it can saturate a NUMA node.